# Error: No available formula with the name "chromedriver"

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, homebrew

**I am trying to start chromedriver in mac**

I have already installed chromedriver using

`brew tap caskroom/cask`

`brew cask install chromedriver`

I keep getting this error when I try to start chromedriver using

`brew services start chromedriver`

**Error: No available formula with the name "chromedriver"**

Any suggestion or help?

Thanks

Comment: can you confirm by using `chromedriver --version`, chrome driver installed or not?

Comment: Yes. I did and It is installed.  `ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689})`

Comment: You can do browser automation without brew install, what is main reason for installing brew ?

Comment: I think brew makes it easy to install. That is why I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe we don't need to start chromedriver anymore. It works without starting it right after installing for mac devices.